# Angular - PipeTransform - Filter observable array

Tags: angular, dictionary, filter, pipe, observable

I have a problem when creating a PipeTransform, the input is Observable<Array> and I want to filter this Array it based on another parameter, but it doesn't work.
Any help where I'm going wrong?

```
export class FilterClientPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(clients: Observable<ClientModel[]>, i1: string): any {

    if (i1 !== '') {
      clients = clients.pipe(
        map((data: ClientModel[]) =>
          data
            .filter(i => i.i1.toLowerCase() === i1)
        ));
      return clients;
    }
    return clients;
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? How do you use the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class FilterClientPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(clients: Observable<ClientModel[]>, i1 : string): ClientModel[] {

    return clients.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(data=> {
        if(i1){
          return data.filter(client => client.i1.toLowerCase().include(i1))
         }
        return data;
       })
     ).toPromise()
 }
```

I hope this will help you. But will be great you can share more information what exactly you want to achieve, then only I will create stackblitz example for you.
Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't work either. Just to explain what I really need: I am displaying data from Observable<ClientModel[]> in the table, based on the input field I want to filter the table and display only Observable<ClientModel[]> that have text from input field i1. That is, PipeTransForm should return me an Observable<ClientModel[]> where the condition that client.i1.toLowerCase().include(i1) is met

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
export class FiletClientPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(clients: Observable<ClientModel[]>, i1 : string): Observable<ClientModel[]> {

    if (i1){
        clients = clients.pipe(map( o=> o.filter(f=> f.i1.toUpperCase() === i1)))
    }

  }
    return clients;

  }
}
```